# Node.JS, Socket.IO & large XML files: extreme performance loss?

Tags: xml, file, node.js, socket.io

I stumbled upon an ugly problem the other day: I'm using XML strings to communicate between server and client and exchange precisely custom defined Data. Works fine so far as long as the size of the XML file isn't too large.

But in one case I need to transmit an XML file with ~35000 rows that, client-side, results in an HTML table with ~2200 table rows.
On the server I'm using the `fs.readFile()` method and then immediately send the content of it. It takes ages (or to be precise: min. 6 seconds) until the `socket.on('message')`-handler is called on the client.

I'm new to Node.js and have been Googling all day yesterday. Does anyone have an idea on how to speed up reading the XML file and transmitting it in the given environment just the tiniest bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got 3 sugggestion that may increase performance:

- Use JSON rather than XML. Much faster to parse and at times it has less size than XML. You can use [node-expat](https://github.com/astro/node-expat) to convert XML to JSON. See this [benchmark](http://www.navioo.com/ajax/ajax_json_xml_Benchmarking.php).
- Make the tables in server-side. Server's are obviously faster than clients. Then you can also use caching.
- I think it is better to use direct AJAX calls, socket.io is heavy and I don't think it is not made for heavy objects.

Comment: Hey Alfred I think you're right with JSON, thanks! I'll definitely give that a chance. My task right now unfortunately is to see how far I get using WebSocket in terms of performance since full duplex communication is worth the try...

Comment: Yep, the use of JSON reduced the time to wait by ~75%!

Answer (score 0):

I've been using https://github.com/astro/node-expat/blob/master/lib/node-expat.js to parse an enormous 37GB XML file.  It supports file streaming and is working great.

```
var expat = require('node-expat');
var fs = require('fs');
var parser = new expat.Parser("UTF-8");
// set up your event listeners here
var fname = "path/to/your/file.xml";
fs.createReadStream(fname).pipe(parser);
```

Setting up sax-style event listeners is pretty easy, let me know if you need help with it.