# Socket.io client socket taking long to respond

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am using socket.io to send/receive messages between client/server. The server has a Redis instance that stores data and responds with the data within milliseconds.

Some of the sockets take very long to return the data (stringified large JSON object) although it is sent from the server side almost immediately. I am therefore looking for suggestion that address the following concerns:

- Is it normal for socket.io to take this long to emit a long string ?
- How can I know which method or socket is doing the emit that takes long ?
- Any further suggestions on how to improve performance?

[image: Dev tools Chrome]

Help really appreciated

UPDATE:

I tried using Webdis to provide the response to the client without having to go to the server to get the Redis results. However although the response appears in a console.log in about 1 second (which is the same as the DOMLoadedContent below), the websocket still takes about 20s and shows 0 bytes as shown below:

[image]

Comment: How long is the string? You refer to it as a “long string”. Is it like megabytes or something?

Comment: @Nate The longest it about 19.5 MegaBytes

Comment: Hey @AfshinGhazi, any luck so far on the issue?

Comment: @ForgetfulFellow no haven't resovled yet. I used Webdis to provide the Redis data quickly to the client instead of the server (which would then provide to the client). However I can't understand why the websocket takes about 20s to finish wheras a console.log of the data takes about 1s.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you've hit issues that others have seen as well with large file uploads using socket.io:

[Node.JS, Socket.IO & large XML files: extreme performance loss?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912295/node-js-socket-io-large-xml-files-extreme-performance-loss)

One possible course of action is to try file streaming in socket.io:
https://gist.github.com/companje/eea17988257a10dcbf04

As for

> How can I know which method or socket is doing the emit that takes
>   long ?

You can always pass in dateTime's into the client's data received from socket.io and then compute the time difference, printing out the methods that it called.

Comment: I’d also be curious of what is being sent that large. If it’s media (image, audio, video) then it would make more sense to send a URL over the socket, and have the browser download the file like normal not through a socket. This approach would reduce load on the socket server and also allow the browser to cache the large data, which is better for everyone.

Comment: @Nate The large data comes from an api call response

Comment: @AfshinGhazi What’s the data type? Because if that’s all JSON data for building a UI, that sounds crazy!